# Distortion Issues When Exporting Cat Rigify Animation

Tags: animation, mesh, export, bones, rigify

I am creating a cat model and rig with a team for a school project. The cat mesh was created in zbrush and has a medium polycount. We followed this tutorial to use rigify with Blender to rig and animate a cat model: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6I9VRGm45HE.
When inside of blender, the animations look fine. When the model is exported as a .fbx with any combination of export settings, it gets distorted and stretched in weird ways. This issue is mainly centered around the neck and head area.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Before Exporting

- Idle animation in Blender (before exporting):
  https://youtu.be/yg6MD-_pQZc
- Sprinting animation in Blender (before
  exporting): https://youtu.be/YjskYxj2j5Y

After exporting

- Idle animation after exporting: https://youtu.be/gsR0fgdxiiA
- Sprinting animation after exporting: https://youtu.be/kDl9N0ryQbg
- Sprinting animation **rig** after exporting:
  https://youtu.be/P8Lzl9fyA70

Image of rig before exporting

[image: Image of rig before exporting]

Image of rig after exporting

[image: Image of the rig after exporting]

Comment: since rigging and exporting is a quite complex process i would recommend providing a blend file so we can check it out.